# Widget update service not working properly

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, networkonmainthread

My widget update service is throwing an:
"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" when I try to get SOAP response from my web server.

I am sure that there is no error with the SOAP code because I use the same code in the app only through an IntentService instead of Service.

I designed my widget base on the last example of: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Error code:
***08-26 19:22:14.931: W/System.err(16244): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException***
08-26 19:22:14.936: W/System.err(16244):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-26 19:22:14.941: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-26 19:22:14.956: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
08-26 19:22:14.956: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
08-26 19:22:14.956: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:120)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:176)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
**08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):  at com.aek.callstatistics.UpdateWidgetService.soapGetOperators(UpdateWidgetService.java:280)
08-26 19:22:14.961: W/System.err(16244):    at com.aek.callstatistics.UpdateWidgetService.callLogUpdate(UpdateWidgetService.java:245)**
08-26 19:22:14.966: W/System.err(16244):    at com.aek.callstatistics.UpdateWidgetService$1.done(UpdateWidgetService.java:481)

Answer (score 0):

This is a safety catch for your app as performing network operations on the main thread of your app will block all other app operations.  Refactor your `Service` to use a background thread to perform the network operations and provide results for your widget.  You could use an `AsyncTask` for this, or get a little fancier and use your own thread pools, etc.